# what is this ornament called?

Tags: theory, notation, brass

Can anybody tell me what this sign is called ?
I thought it was a mordent, but why isn't it written above the lines, why is it so short? 
Do you know any theory page on it?
[image]

Comment: I assume it is an articulation rather as an ornament. While it seems, that it is covered by Unicode as [Stroke-2](http://unicode-table.com/en/1D19C/), no explanation is found there.

Comment: thanks for answering. But shouldn't articulations be written above or below the note (and not next to it) ?

Comment: @froggynathy A lot of jazz articulations are written next to the note- for example, falls, bends, doits, shakes. They make more sense there, because the symbol is a visual representation of how you play the start/end of the note.

Answer (score 8):

It's a [turn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornament_(music)#Turn), apparently sometimes called a 'flip':

[image: Turn]

Source: http://www.timusic.net/wp-content/uploads/jazz+artikulation.pdf, Page 6.